# Do we have text-to-speech online services?

Tags: webapp-rec

I am looking for text-to-speech synthesizers online services. I am also interested in those that support English/French/Spanish.

Which can you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [AT&T's](http://www2.research.att.com/~ttsweb/tts/demo.php) is limited to 300 characters
- [SpokenText](http://www.spokentext.net/) covers English, French, Spanish & German. Online version limited to 100 characters.
- There are a few voices at [Read The Words](http://www.readthewords.com/) but you do have to register to get anything other than the US male/female voices.
- [Cepstral](http://cepstral.com/demos/) has some demos with a wider range of voices
- [Vozme](http://vozme.com/index.php?lang=en) - can save as MP3 but the quality is lousy compared to IVONA, or Google's TTS
- [Expressivo](http://say.expressivo.com/) - not many characters allowed, interesting selection of voices - English, Romanian & Polish - easy to link to this as they just read the string in the URL
- [Ivona](http://ivona.com) - high quality. Seems pretty similar to Expressivo in functionality & voices. Online demo limited to 250 characters.